# Make SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND available in AuthorizedKeysCommand context

Tags: ssh

Using SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in AuthorizedKeys is so helpful, I'd like to know how to access it in the AuthorizedKeysCommand context (via env ?). Is this possible ?  can anybody give me advice on going into this ?

If possible, I'll use this SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND to send client specifics information to the AuthorizedKeysCommand script. Currently, the only alternative to this is to use the login itself (we have around 30k+ different 'hosts' that  might want to connect to our servers) to identify the client, but that come with the need of a custom nss endpoint configuration (we use libnss-pgsql2 ) to support dynamic user lookup, and more work (to manage uid & co)

Using 'one' standard user file was enough (and a lot simplier), as those hosts don’t need to do anything but to setup a revert port forwarding rule, and are bound to a very limited shell.

My (now useless) /home/host_controler/.ssh/authorized_keys  file (build on a cron run) was like :
command="limited_shell.sh  --host_id=XXX1 $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ssh-rsa pubkey of host 1"
command="limited_shell.sh --host_id=XXX2 $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ssh-rsa pubkey of host 2"
command="limited_shell.sh --host_id=XXX3 $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ssh-rsa pubkey of host 3"
...

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: See https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2014-February/032181.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the case switching into your limited_shell.sh or write another wrapper.
There may be possibilities to put your specific config needs into the central ssh_config, but I have never done that, so can't help further.